# Is dpkg available for Cygwin?

Tags: dpkg, cygwin

I don't use Windows all that often, but I've found my self in a position where I'm stuck in front of one quite a bit temporarily. So I've been investigating Cygwin. My question is dpkg available for Cygwin? My Google searches seem to show that it was at least at one point, but I can't find a package. If it isn't availiable as a package does anyone have any tips/experience getting it running?

I'm not trying to create a Cygwin Debian port (although it sounds as if this was attempted in the past). At the minimum, I'd simply like to be able to build Debian source packages while on the Windows machine. (Yes, I know I could ssh over to a Debian box.)

[Cygwin is apparently on topic here](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/436/cygwin-on-topic), but it might not be the best place for this question. I hope this is ok...

Comment: This is a very reasonable thing to ask for. The equivalent for building RPM's (`rpmbuild`) is in Cygwin.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An attempt to get dpkg working has been abandoned, according to [THIS](http://sourceforge.net/news/?group_id=251174) sourceforge page that was setup to investigate getting dpkg to work on Windows Cygwin.

**Stick to a Virtual Box instance or SSH.**

EDIT: If you are really interested, there is a huge thread about trying to get it work [here](http://www.mail-archive.com/debian-win32@lists.debian.org/msg00210.html).

Answer (score 1):

With some wrangling you can get dpkg to compile and run under a recent Cygwin environment, you will have to 'autoreconf' the source repository from git and then manually edit the generated 'configure' script with hardcoded values for os_type, cpu_type and dpkg_arch(=cygwin64, arbitrarily chosen but you'll want to build your .deb packages with Architecture equaling this value).

Also: [This patch](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c5cc0afa87ae91b3299365b9f1f0a72d) - and oh, disable building start-stop-daemon

[image: Screenshot, mintty, tmux, dpkg, cmake]

Answer (score 0):

There is a sort of package manager for cygwin, called [apt-cyg](https://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg), but it's a 3rd party package, not part of the cygwin project itself.

If you're thinking about cygwin, you might check out [Babun](http://babun.github.io/). I just learned about it this week, so I can't vouch for it completely, but I like what I've see so far.

It's a cygwin fork that is more feature-ful out of the box setup. Amongst other improvements, it features `pact`, an "advanced package manager (like apt-get or yum)", and also an "Auto update feature"